# sum two list with eachother without sum function

Tags: python, list

I am writing code about two lists and the sum element without using the sum function. So I need to return the sum of its elements. How do I define a list c with the total number of list a and b

The code below is what I already tried.

```
def add(list_a, list_b):
    list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    list_c = []

for i in range (0,5):
    list_c.append(list_a[i]+second[i])

print (list_c)
```

The error code:

> File "sum.py", line 7, in
>
> list_c.append(list_a[i]+second[i])
>
> NameError: name 'list_c' is not defined

Comment: There is no reason to define the lists in a function. That limits them to the function scope rather than being global objects

Comment: What is the purpose of the add function here? Just move your list definitions out of there and get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem. It should work if you indent the `for` block and the `print` statement. You also have a typo, `second[i]` should be `list_b[i]`.

```
def add(list_a, list_b): 
    list_c = [] 

    for i in range(0,5): 
        list_c.append(list_a[i]+list_b[i]) 

    return(list_c)

list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(add(list_a, list_b))
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

A really short way to write this would be:

```
print([x+y for x,y in zip(list_a, list_b)])
```

It only works when the lists have the same length.

Comment: @roganjosh I don't know. It's the  `add` function OP tried to declare. I might have gotten the question wrong though.

Comment: The `add` function doesn't make sense here, the parameters are immediately overwritten so serves no purpose.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone yeah that's also a problem. I think they meant to declare it outside the function. Did a copy-paste and forgot to move it :) Fixed, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. First, you don't need to define your lists inside a function, and secondly you were referencing the second list as `second` instead of `list_b`. The below is all you need:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_c = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    list_c.append(list_a[i] + list_b[i])

print (list_c)
```

Alternatively if you want to use it as a reusable function then you can move your loop logic into the function itself and pass the lists as parameters:

```
def add(list_a, list_b): 
    summed_list = [] 

    for i in range(0, 5): 
        summed_list.append(list_a[i] + list_b[i]) 

    return summed_list

summed = add([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(summed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `map` in order to achieve that following way:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def add(a,b):
    return list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,list_a,list_b))
print(add(list_a,list_b))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```